# MySQLi - Get table value as string instead of object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to use php to retrieve both the **name** and **userEmail** values from my **Users** MySQL table seen here:
[image]

I'm using the following code in attempt to grab the currently logged-in user's **name** and **userEmail**:

```
<?php
session_start();
#connect to MySQL database
require_once("settings.php");
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

#get username of current session
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

#get userEmail of logged-in user from database
$sql = "SELECT userEmail from Users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$replyTo = mysqli_fetch_field($result);

#get name of logged-in user from database
$sql2 = "SELECT name from Users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' LIMIT 1";
$result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
$name = mysqli_fetch_field($result2);
?>
```

Then I try passing the **$replyTo** and **$name** values into a function that only accepts strings (the `setFrom()` function from PHPmailer to be precise):

```
$mail->setFrom($replyTo, $name);
```

...and get the following errors:

**Warning**: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in **/var/www/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php** on line **489** (this object was $replyTo)

**Catchable fatal error:** Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in **/var/www/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php** on line **490** (this object was $name)

Using Chrome Logger to debug, I found these to be the values of **$userEmail** and **$name**:

[image]

Comment: You are using the wrong function. [mysqli::fetch_field()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) returns column meta data - not the value.

Comment: Ha, yes, I would think it is. I usually default to W3Schools, though I've seen comments on here of people strongly preaching against it. For some reason, Google and W3schools are failing me on this particular item (More like I'm failing myself actually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get email and name with single query - make use of prepared statement for security reason(SQLIA)

```
#get userEmail of logged-in user from database
$sql = "SELECT userEmail,name from Users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
// this is prepared statement and prevent form sql injection attack
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param('s',$username);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
// fetch first record in associative array
$userDetail = $result->fetch_assoc();
if($userDetail)
{
   $replyTo = $userDetail['userEmail'];
   $name = $uerDetail['name'];
   $mail->setFrom($replyTo, $name);
}
else
{
   echo 'user not found';
}
```

Comment: yes that is `bind_param` and keep `username = ?` .. if you make `WHERE username = '{$username}'` then bind_param is not required and is a bad approach to

Comment: It now assigns them the correct values. Thanks so much!